# Is it possible to implement a way to "guess" this date format based on the information in the array?

Tags: javascript, date-format

In JavaScript Language ,

I have an array ... maybe it look like this

```
var all_date = new Array( "11/12/2009", "31/12/2010", "29/12/2011", "17/09/2011" );
```

Is it possible to implement a way to "guess" this date format based on the information in the array and perhaps suggest to user which date format is most likely? Such as ... DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well of course, if the data happens to conveniently contain day values greater than 12 and have four-digit years (as the data you've quoted does), you're not guessing, you can be certain you've got the right format.

But if it happens that all of the day values in the data are 12 or lower, it's impossible to be certain whether the data is in U.S. MM/DD/YYYY format or the more common DD/MM/YYYY.

So no, you can't *reliably* infer the format in the general case. The source of the data should provide the format information (in documentation, etc.), and ideally use a less ambiguous format such as YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: Good reasonable, maybe one day someone will produce the library to solved this problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to a certain degree, yes, you can. One obvious method is by using regular expressions. Suppose you have a date, like 2020-10-31, you can test it against a RegExp, extract tokens(year, month and day of month) and once tokens are identified, you can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) them to their corresponding format tokens(YYYY, MM and DD).

Now consider the RegExp, `/^(\d{4})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])$/`; put in simple words, it matches string of the form (4-digit year)-(month, maybe)-(day of month, maybe); parentheses imply [capture groups](https://github.com/learnbyexample/learn_js_regexp/blob/master/js_regexp.md#capture-groups). Capture groups here, will essentially pull out the tokens for you(year, month and day of month parts). Try out the following snippet,

```js
console.log('2020-10-31'.match(/^(\d{4})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])$/));
```

Once the tokens have been identified, it's easy to construct the format string, YYYY-MM-DD.

Be warned though, if the date is ambiguous, you can't accurately determine token semantics. Consider the date 01/01/2020, it could be any of DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY. Nonetheless, the method works quite well for standard date-time formats([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3)).

Detailed references :-

1. [Regular expressions](https://github.com/learnbyexample/learn_js_regexp/blob/master/js_regexp.md)
2. [Here](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2c0b063b3bf95a285f9b38c173e262b6416c2e7f/src/lib/create/from-string.js#L58-L112) is a snippet from [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) source code which does what you asked, but only for ISO 8601 compliant dates
3. [Here](https://github.com/apoorv-mishra/moment-guess) is a package I wrote, which does the same thing for other formats as well, accounting for the ambiguities.